# How do I open the Parity browser interface?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, parity-io

I'm a completely beginner in the blockchain world. I'm following a tutorial on how to develop DApps provided by the company I'm doing my academic practices in, but I think it's kind of old.

In the video, they download a parityInstaller.exe file but in modern releases it doesn't seem to exist anymore, just a binary (we use Windows).

So after that they execute the following command:

> parity --chain ropsten --rpccorsdomain localhost --jsonrpc-apis
>   web3,eth,net,personal,parity,parity_set,traces,rpc,parity_accounts,signer
>   ui

A browser tab opens (127.0.0.1, no port is displayed) with the Parity interface.

I do the same but it doesn't recognize the "signer ui" part, I've left it as "signer" instead. The program itself detects a deprecated parameter so I use the one that suggests me instead. All okay. But no browser tab pops up, and I can't access the Parity interface through 127.0.0.1 (tried many ports as well). I think it's something that got changed at some point or it simply works differently in the binary version. I can't find any relevant information about it.

May someone please explain me how to make it work nowadays? I'd highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the "browser interface" currently lives in github.com/parity-js/shell but as you can see, it has been removed from the parity-ethereum client, and it's currently unmaintained and incompatible with the recent versions of parity-ethereum.

I would check out remix.ethereum.org for smart contract development, as it is still maintained and up to date.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joshua! I've been told to learn about blockchains and contract development but I haven't been given many specifications (and the project I'll be working on hasn't been fully defined yet), so I'm really lost atm. 

I've followed many tutorials but I'm not exactly sure on how to test and apply the contracts I develop. I've tried to set up a blockchain but everything that I find seems to be outdated or even deprecated - most projects that I download to test don't work for this reason.  May you please give me some advice on how to focus my learning? 

Thank you very much.

Comment: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/ < solidity documentation / https://wiki.parity.io/Demo-PoA-tutorial < set up a parity network with a few nodes (or just use `--dev` for development) and geth: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Setting-up-private-network-or-local-cluster /  https://truffleframework.com/ganache < a "chain" specifically for testing (formerly known as testrpc) and more generally the https://truffleframework.com has multiple extremely useful tools after you've prototyped something in https://remix.ethereum.org (docs at https://remix.readthedocs.io).